# AWS Lambda static IP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, firewall

I'm trying to access a external MyQSL database (Not AWS RDS), and I need to have a static IP in order to open up the firewall for accepting connections. Is it possible to set a static IP with a Lambda instance? If not what are some other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to deploy your Lambda function into a VPC and within the VPC, provide NAT Gateway. Then assign an Elastic IP (static IP) to the NAT Gateway. These two links describe it step-by-step:

- [AWS: How to Create a Static IP Address Using a NAT Gateway (Medium)](https://medium.com/@gboyegadada/aws-how-to-create-a-static-ip-address-using-a-nat-gateway-845c884aa4bd)
- [How do I give internet access to my Lambda function in a VPC? (AWS Knowledge Center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Answer (score 4):

I have to do this every year or two and always forget how to do it :) Fortunately, I've discovered the AWS now has a wizard that steps you through this process: https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=ap-southeast-2#wizardFullpagePublicAndPrivate:

The wizard didn't pick up my Elastic IP Allocation ID so I had to manually paste it in from the Elastic IP section of the VPC console but after that everything works. https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=ap-southeast-2#Addresses:sort=PublicIp

Then you just set up your lambda function to use that VPC. The only remaining gotcha is to select the Private Subnet that the wizard created rather than the public subnet (of course).  [image]

If you are deploying your Lambda functions using SAM rather than the console you can direct your function to use the VPC by including Policy and VpcConfig sections in your SAM template as shown below.

[image]

In another year or two when I have to do this again, I'll hopefully find this answer :)

Comment: I'd recommend to use an IaC tool such as Terraform instead of clicking around. Then you won't forget it, because you don't have to remember anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

What you should do instead is:

- deploy the Lambda function into the private subnet of a VPC
- deploy a NAT Gateway (or NAT instance) into a public subnet of the VPC
- deploy an Internet Gateway into the VPC
- give the NAT an Elastic IP
- make the NAT be the default route for the Lambda subnet
- whitelist the NAT's Elastic IP at the remote firewall